# How to remove "diffgr:before" content from returned dataset via webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, dataset

I have a web method:

```
public DataSet SyncedWall()
    {
            DataSet dst = dscomment;
            dst.Tables[0].Rows[i]["WallInfo"] = "my own modified value";
            return dst;
    }
```

Although the real method is big but this is a minified version.

Following is the xml output received from the web method:

```
<DataSet>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet">
<!-- Schema goes here.. -->
</xs:schema>

<diffgr:diffgram>

<NewDataSet>
<!-- Dataset values goes here... -->
</NewDataSet>

<diffgr:before>
<!-- Here are the original modified (unwanted) values -->
</diffgr:before>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

What I want is to remove the `<diffgr:before>` tag and its inner contents.
How to do that?

Comment: The best practice is to not return .NET-specific types like `DataSet` at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it doesn't resolve the problem. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hurreeyyyyyy!!!

I've found the answer after scratching my head upto couples of hours. :P
Before returning the dataset just call for `datasetObject.AcceptChanges();` and you're done.

So here is the code:

```
public DataSet SyncedWall()
    {
            DataSet dst = dscomment;
            dst.Tables[0].Rows[i]["WallInfo"] = "my own modified value";
            dst.AcceptChanges();
            return dst;
    }
```

Comment: Still includes a schema, right? Also, if this solves your problem, then you should accept your own answer.

Comment: Is there a way to implement this kind of Webmethods in JAX-WS? Any help much appreciated