# kSOAP2 double ID exception

Tags: android, exception, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, ksoap

I am attempting to use kSOAP 2 in my android application, and when I try to perform a particular webservice request, I end up getting thrown a "double ID" exception.  I was able to find where this gets thrown in the kSOAP source code, it is in the `SoapSerializationEnvelope` class method  `public Object read()`  Here is an excerpt from that code showing the exception being thrown:

```
        if (id != null) {
            Object hlp = idMap.get(id);
            if (hlp instanceof FwdRef) {
                FwdRef f = (FwdRef) hlp;
                do {
                    if (f.obj instanceof KvmSerializable)
                        ((KvmSerializable) f.obj).setProperty(f.index, obj);
                    else
                        ((Vector) f.obj).setElementAt(obj, f.index);
                    f = f.next;
                } while (f != null);
            } else if (hlp != null)
                throw new RuntimeException("double ID");
            idMap.put(id, obj);
        }
```

I'm not at all sure what this exception is about, or how I can fix it.  Anyone know what the deal with this exception is?

Thanks

Edit:

It should be noted that I am also using a SOAP webservice connection method in the iOS version of this application, and the same exact request does not have any problems.

New information:

Upon closer inspection, the problem seems to be resulting from the xml response I am getting containing a `<diffgr:before>` element, which has tables with the same ID as above.  I think this is the cause of the problem, the other requests I have performed up to this point do not have that element in them, and do not have the exception.  So to add to the question: can I stop the webservice from sending this block in its response, or get kSOAP to ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by removing the `diffgr:before` element the webservice was sending.  I did that thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6073129/650233)

Answer (score 0):

well, I had the same problem too, but I had no `diffgr:before` in the xml response (And I can't change the webservice at all). Anyway, the problem was due to some empty values in the response. Using [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/)
I managed to remove all empty elements and the it worked like charm. This is done by converting the response to string, loading it into `nu.xom.Document` element, remove the empty elements from the document and revert it back to InputStream for parsing with ksoap2