# Weird behavior on KSOAP and .net Services

Tags: .net, web-services, ksoap2

So, i tried another approach to a problem i posted earlier (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812507/ksoap2-double-id)

I changed from returnin a DataSet to return a simple array of string. Here's the webMethod

```
<WebMethod(Description:="Almacena una lectura, la posición del lecturista y revisa si sigue activo el servicio")> _
Public Function guardarDatos(ByVal Lecturas As Object, ByVal id_lec As String, ByVal usuario As String, ByVal sobrelectura As String, ByVal latitud As String, ByVal longitud As String, ByVal precision As String, ByVal pin As String) As String()
    Dim respuesta As String() = {"dummie", "0", "0", "0"}
    If ingresarLecturas(Lecturas, id_lec, usuario, sobrelectura) Then
        respuesta(1) = "1"
    End If
    If guardaLocalizacion(id_lec, usuario, latitud, longitud, precision, pin) Then
        respuesta(2) = "1"
    End If
    If gpsActivo() Then
        respuesta(3) = "1"
    End If
    Return respuesta
End Function
```

But here's the strange thing. Notice how the element 0 of my array states "dummie". That's because when retrieving the reponse of the webService, `SoapSerializationEnvelope` (`sse` for short) `bodyIn` element gave me `ClassCastException` when getting the properties, with either `getResponse()` or `getResult()` i could indeed get the values withouth problem, but only those in index 1 and 2, the one in index 0 always threw me a `ClassCastException`, so i tried adding a "dummie" index 0 on my returning array and just store the final values on indexes 1, 2 and 3, and it worked, I can retrieve the values, but `getProperty(0)` keeps sending me a `ClassCastException`. Any ideas???? Pretty weird huh?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set respuesta(0), so it's Nothing. Which would cause a class cast exception or null reference exception depending on the caller.

Comment: When i define the variable respuesta as a String array, notice i also definde the content of the array, and respuesta(0) is the String "dummie"