# java.lang.RuntimeException: double ID

Tags: android, soap, datatable

I am getting this exception while calling the web service. The server returns me the data in the from of .net DataTable.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: double ID
11-25 19:06:46.617: W/System.err(11949):    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:407)
11-25 19:06:46.618: W/System.err(11949):    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:273)
11-25 19:06:46.620: W/System.err(11949):    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:389)
11-25 19:06:46.621: W/System.err(11949):    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:273)
11-25 19:06:46.622: W/System.err(11949):    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:389)
11-25 19:06:46.624: W/System.err(11949):    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:273)
11-25 19:06:46.625: W/System.err(11949):    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:389)
11-25 19:06:46.626: W/System.err(11949):    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:151)
11-25 19:06:46.627: W/System.err(11949):    at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)
11-25 19:06:46.628: W/System.err(11949):    at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:100)
11-25 19:06:46.629: W/System.err(11949):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:197)
11-25 19:06:46.630: W/System.err(11949):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
11-25 19:06:46.632: W/System.err(11949):    at com.datacomp.webservice.WebServiceDroidConn.GetBankEmiDetails(WebServiceDroidConn.java:93)
11-25 19:06:46.633: W/System.err(11949):    at com.datacomp.magicsales.MainActivity$StartGetBankEmiDetails.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:130)
11-25 19:06:46.634: W/System.err(11949):    at com.datacomp.magicsales.MainActivity$StartGetBankEmiDetails.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
11-25 19:06:46.636: W/System.err(11949):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
11-25 19:06:46.637: W/System.err(11949):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-25 19:06:46.638: W/System.err(11949):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-25 19:06:46.639: W/System.err(11949):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
11-25 19:06:46.640: W/System.err(11949):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-25 19:06:46.641: W/System.err(11949):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-25 19:06:46.642: W/System.err(11949):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your webservice, call `AcceptChanges()` on your datatable before returning it.

Comment: can you give me detail explanation?

Comment: here's where i found it - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073129/how-to-remove-diffgrbefore-content-from-returned-dataset-via-webservice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073129/how-to-remove-diffgrbefore-content-from-returned-dataset-via-webservice)